# Function decomposition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

the roots($s_1, s_2, s_3, \ \dots$) of the $f(s)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-s}}$ are obtained from setting the equation

$1-e^{-s}=0$; the roots can be obtained: $s_1=0, s_1=2\pi, s_2=-2\pi, s_3=4\pi \ \dots$

So $f(s)$ can be decomposed into the form of
 $f(s)= \frac{a_0}{s - 0} + \frac{a_1}{s+2\pi} + \frac{a_2}{s-2\pi}+ \frac{a_3}{s+4\pi} + \frac{a_4}{s-4\pi} + \dots$

we can obtain the coefficients as following. take $a_3$ as a example

$f(s) \times (s + 4\pi) = \frac{a_0\times (s + 4\pi)}{s - 0} + \frac{a_1 \times (s + 4\pi)}{s+2\pi} + \frac{a_2 \times (s + 4\pi)}{s-2\pi}+ \frac{a_3 \times (s + 4\pi)}{s+4\pi} + \frac{a_4 \times (s + 4\pi)}{s-4\pi} + \dots$

let $s=-4\pi$. $a_3$ can be calculated: $a_3=1$.

similar calculation can be make to get $a_0=1 \ \ a_1=1 \ \ a_2=1 \ \dots$
so the final expression is

$\frac{1}{1-e^{-s}} = \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{s+2\pi} + \frac{1}{s-2\pi} + \frac{1}{s+4\pi} + \frac{1}{s-4\pi} + \dots$

it seems everything is right.

set 
$$\begin{align} s=1+i; \qquad & \frac{1}{1-e^{-s}}=1.08-0.41i;\\ 
           & \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{s+2\pi} + \frac{1}{s-2\pi} + \frac{1}{s+4\pi} + \frac{1}{s-4\pi} + \dots = 0.58-0.42i \end{align}$$

only the imaginary part is the same. the real part is different.

Anyone can explain why? Thanks!

Can anybody give a direct result of decomposition?

Comment: It would help if you can format this using MathJax

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: this is the partial [fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of meromorphic functions, that you can deduce from the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Comment: and you can deduce the correct partial fraction expansion from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Cotangent

Comment: the complex analysis is beyond what I can do now. have to pick up the graduate textbook. can you give me a direct result. the decomposition is sampled spectrum obtained by convolution. the original equation is obtained from direct sum of a geometric progression. they should be the same. This is Fourier spectrum of a exponent decaying signal.